# Decimal passed incorrectly from C# to SQL Server with TableAdapters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, tableadapter

Yesterday I noticed an odd behaviour when using TableAdapters, for some reason when passing a decimal < 0.1 it makes it into an integer. For example if I pass 1.0123, I can see 1.0123 in SQL Profiler, but if I pass 0.0123 I will get 123. Is there a known issue? You can do the following steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a new database TestDatabase, and create the following stored procedure

   ```
   create proc DecimalParametersSelect
   (
       @Foo decimal(10,5)
   )

   as

   select @Foo
   ```
2. Create a new project and add a new DataSet file SampleDataset. Add a new TableAdapter and add DecimalParametersSelect as Select procedure (it should be the only one in your db).
3. Run your project and try to select some data, e.g.

   ```
   using (SampleDatasetTableAdapters.DecimalParametersSelectTableAdapter dta = new SampleDatasetTableAdapters.DecimalParametersSelectTableAdapter())
   {
       var table = dta.GetData(0.01588M);
   }
   ```

In profiler you should see that the value passed in is 1588 (interestingly the value returned is recognized correctly in C# as 0.01588)

Comment: So what is a DecimalParametersSelectTableAdapter ? Is does not appear to be part of the .Net Base Class Library.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - I see 0.01588 in profiler (VS2012RC, SQL Server 2012)

Comment: Looks like it might be specific to 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a display bug in SQL Profiler when the `TextData` column is not included in the trace and the text of the RPC command is reconstructed from another source (presumably `BinaryData`).

I followed your steps and was able to repo on SQL 2008 R2 using a default trace in SQL profiler.

However, when the trace properties are changed to include the `TextData` column for `RPC:Completed`, the correct command is displayed.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it. I have actually stumbled across it chasing a different bug, and I thought the two were connected. Looks like I have to keep looking. Thanks for you help.