# SQL Server Profiler and Yellow Backgrounded Cells

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

When viewing returned data in SQL Profiler, some cells appear with a yellowish background and others with a white background. Empty BinaryData fields all seem to appear this way but some TextData field that contain commands such as 'exec sp_reset_connection' also show this behavior.

Does anyone have an idea what the yellow means and if that same criteria that causes the background to turn yellow can be accessed through trace filters?

Comment: In Management Studio grid results a yellow background means `NULL`. I guess it is probably similar in Profiler that the yellow ones are for columns not supplied as they are not relevant for an event or have a NULL value.

Comment: Hi Martin...thanks for the reply. That is what I thought a first also and it holds true for the Binary Data field but for the TextData fields, there are plenty of rows that have a yellow background and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow background means for `TextData` appears to mean that the text in the cell has been derived from a value in another column - most likely `BinaryData`.

There are [some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845012/decimal-passed-incorrectly-from-c-sharp-to-sql-server-with-tableadapters/11845924#11845924) where the values in `TextData` derived in this way can be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks much...this makes sense looking at my results