# Strange behavior with c# and sql server decimal data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal

I'm experiencing the following issue: I am trying to call a stored procedure which accepts as an input a **decimal(18,6)** parameter, and passing it a C# decimal value.

See the following code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = DB.GetConnection();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = Conn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "spInsertUpdateCustomerOrderItem";

                 if (CustomerOrderItem.Weight == null)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", DBNull.Value);
                else
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", CustomerOrderItem.Weight.Value); //CustomerOrderItem.Weight.Value is a C# decimal 
(....)
(....)
```

The point is that, when the value of the parameter is between 0 and 1 (for instance, **0.0159**), the parameter is passed to the stored procedure losing the leading zeros (in this case **159**).

I can see this clearly using the SQL server profiler, where I see the following query executed:

```
exec spInsertUpdateCustomerOrderItem @Weight=159 (...)
```

If the value is, instead, above zero (e.g. 1.0125), the parameter is passed correctly.

If, to make a try, I cast the value to double before adding it, it is passed correctly (but this solution is not viable as I need to use decimal values).

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and SQL Server 2014.

Any ideas of why I get this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the value being passed from? Could it be using different regional settings, where the `.` is interpreted as a thousands separator?

Comment: Is there the same behavior using `SqlParameter` : `SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Weight", SqlDbType.Decimal, CustomerOrderItem.Weight.Value);` then `command.Parameters.Add(param);` ?

Comment: See this post, may be the same issue you're seeing with the data coming from the profiler: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11845012/412451

Comment: You should be explicit with datatypes when adding parameters. The AddWithValue does not always get things correct. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Unfortunately I did already try creating the parameter as a `SqlParameter`  without using the `AddithValue` method, but it doesn't change the situation...

The data coming from the profiler is correct in this case as the data inserted into the table is wrong...

And I don't think it'a a matter of regional settings, as the client is on the same machine of the server, and anyhow I'm passing the value without any possibility to specify the culture. Keep also in mind that decimal values greater than 1 are passed properly!